# Optimizar consulta SQL usando Eloquent de Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Espero que estén todos bien, tengo la siguiente consulta en mi sistema.

```
public function visits()
{

    foreach ($this->countrys as $country) 
    {   
        $query = Visit::where('country',$country)->count();
        $visits[$country]=$query;

    }

    return $visits;
}
```

La consulta va iterando el siguiente array

```
public $countrys = array('AF','AX','AL','DZ','AS','AD','AO','AI','AQ','AG','AR','AM','AW','AU','AT','AZ','BS','BH','BD','BB','BY','BE','BZ','BJ','BM','BT','BO','BQ','BA','BW','BV','BR','IO','VG','BN','BG','BF','BI','KH','CM','CA','CV','KY','CF','TD','CL','CN','CX','CC','CO','KM','CK','CR','HR','CU','CW','CY','CZ','CD','DK','DJ','DM','DO','TL','EC','EG','SV','GQ','ER','EE','ET','FK','FO','FJ','FI','FR','GF','PF','TF','GA','GM','GE','DE','GH','GI','GR','GL','GD','GP','GU','GT','GG','GN','GW','GY','HT','HM','HN','HK','HU','IS','IN','ID','IR','IQ','IE','IM','IL','IT','CI','JM','JP','JE','JO','KZ','KE','KI','XK','KW','KG','LA','LV','LB','LS','LR','LY','LI','LT','LU','MO','MK','MG','MW','MY','MV','ML','MT','MH','MQ','MR','MU','YT','MX','FM','MD','MC','MN','ME','MS','MA','MZ','MM','NA','NR','NP','NL','AN','NC','NZ','NI','NE','NG','NU','NF','KP','MP','NO','OM','PK','PW','PS','PA','PG','PY','PE','PH','PN','PL','PT','PR','QA','CG','RE','RO','RU','RW','BL','SH','KN','LC','MF','PM','VC','WS','SM','ST','SA','SN','RS','CS','SC','SL','SG','SX','SK','SI','SB','SO','ZA','GS','KR','SS','ES','LK','SD','SR','SJ','SZ','SE','CH','SY','TW','TJ','TZ','TH','TG','TK','TO','TT','TN','TR','TM','TC','TV','VI','UG','UA','AE','GB','US','UM','UY','UZ','VU','VA','VE','VN','WF','EH','YE','ZM','ZW');
```

y el resultado es este mas o menos este, claro mas resumido

```
array["AF"=>32,"AX"=>21];//Asi sucesivamente hasta obtener todos lo resultados de array
```

Pero existe un problema de rendimiento y es que son como 251 consultas a la base de datos y cada vez que entro en el dashboard de mi aplicación.

Existe alguna manera de hacer un count de cada uno de los parámetro del array a la base de datos en una única consulta?

las columnas de la tabla son las siguientes:
 id, ip, country, created_at y updated_at

Gracias disculpen la ignorancia.

Comment: hola, deberías agregar la estructura de las tablas, duda: ¿por que debe iterar sobre ese array? ese array viene de una tabla?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la tabla registro las visitas a mi sitio, obtengo la ip y a través de un servicio de terceros obtengo el país de procedencia, luego lo registro en la base de datos. Lo que intento es de obtener todas la visitas de un determinado país para mostrarlo en las estadísticas del sitio, una de las formas que encontré es la que describí en la pregunta pero no es eficiente, existirá alguna manera de hacerlo mas fácil sin sobre cargar el sistema? Necesito los resultados como los del array de mustra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de investigar un rato conseguí la siguiente solución por si a alguien le puede servir.

```
public function visits()
{


    $visits = Visit::select('country')
                    ->selectRaw('count(*) as totalCountry')
                    ->groupBy('country')
                    ->get();

    return $visits;

}
```